# Progress bar delay jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple slider with a progress bar, and is working fine, but during the transition for the next slider, the progress starts immediately, not taking into consideration the transition time. I am trying to add a `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` effect but it's not working properly.

Could you please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np8oh613/)?

## JavaScript

```
bar = $('.progress_bar');
time = 3000;

function run() {
  bar.width(0);
  bar.animate({
    'width': "100%"
  }, time, run).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
}

$("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();
//bar.stop(true, true).css("width", 0).animate({'width': "100%"}, time, run);

setInterval(function () {
  $('#slideshow > li:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, time);

run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweek your code and finally reached here:

```
bar = $('.progress_bar');
time = 3000;

function run(){
  bar.width(0);
  bar.animate({'width': "100%"}, time,function(){
    change();run();
  }).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
}
$("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();


var change = function() { 
  $('#slideshow > li:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
};

run();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9c1xj3/1/) //updated added proper path of images

**Description:** Instead of running both function independently I connected then when progress bar finish I am changing slide with `change` function. So I have removed `setInterval` and calling every time finishing of progress bar.

---

**Updates:** Your can't see fade out/in because after animation instantly you are calling `run` again, I made following change: calling `run` after `fadeout` callback. Still you can't see fadeIn effect because that time bar's percentage is `0%`.

```
function run(){
  bar.width(0);
  bar.fadeIn(500,function(){
    bar.animate({'width': "100%"}, time).fadeOut(500,function(){
      change();run();
    });
  });
}
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9c1xj3/2/)

Comment: thank you! the only problem is that the bar id not fading out/in, instead it just hides, making the effect a bit ugly, how could i fix that?

Comment: See updated answer @user1765661. This may be expected output. If you still want to see `fadeIn` effect also then see http://jsfiddle.net/jp9c1xj3/4/. But this is looking ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/np8oh613/4/)**

```
bar = $('.progress_bar');
time = 3000;

function run(){
  bar.width(0);
  bar.animate({'width': "100%"}, time, run)
   .fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500,function(){
     setTimeout(function() { 
       animation();
    }, time);
  });
}
function animation(){
  $("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > li:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  },  time);
}
animation();
run();
```

Comment: First time completion of progress  bar slide not changing. Second time its working.

Comment: fixed it check the answer again